# How to upload and download Hive file using GoogleDriveApi in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, hive, google-drive-api

I am working on the Flutter app where I want to upload and download hive file to/from **GoogleDrive** using **GoogleDriveAPI**. I'm unsure how to do the file upload, and download process. Can someone provide ***step by step guide*** or ***sample code*** on how to authenticate my app with the Google Drive API and how to upload/download Hive files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.